# Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded in multipe processing

Tags: python

i trying run multipe processing with ThreadPool and i have error `maximum recursion depth exceeded`

this is my code:

```
def extract_all_social_link(bio_url):
    data = extract_all_social_link(bio_url)
    return data
def run_extract_all_social_link(df, max_count, displays_steps = 1000):
    tt = time.time()
    user_data = []
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUM_WORKERS) as executor:
        future_to_url = dict()
        cnt = 0
        for _, row in df.iterrows():
            bio_url = row["bio_url"]
            if cnt > max_count:
                break
            if pd.isna(bio_url):
                continue
            future = executor.submit(extract_all_social_link, bio_url)
            future_to_url[future] = (bio_url)
            cnt += 1
        future_iter = concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url)
        total = len(future_to_url)
        for cnt, future in tqdm(enumerate(future_iter), total=total):
            if (cnt+1) % displays_steps == 0:
                tt1 = time.time()
                print(f"{cnt+1} requests in {tt1 - tt:.3f} seconds")
                tt = tt1
            bio_url = future_to_url[future]
            try:
                data = future.result()
            except Exception as exc:
                print(f"{bio_url} generated an exception: {exc}")
        return user_data
```

`

and this is error:

```
generated an exception: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't even try to change the recursion limit config.
You have to change the code of `extract_all_social_link()` that's called recursively with always the same arg `bio_url`.

```py
def extract_all_social_link(bio_url):
    data = extract_all_social_link(bio_url)  # infinite recursion
    return data  # never reached !!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view and increase this limit using https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit
but it's bad practice in general, since it's a safeguard against stack overflows.
Find a way to avoid so much recursion by refactoring your code.